# Update data in the closed workbook by using SQL

Tags: sql, excel

I have a closed workbook, and I'm trying to update some column values to Null. I'm using a ADO connection and a SQL query to make the updates on the data in the worksheets. Here I'm setting three column values to Null, but it doesn't seem to work. I don't see what's wrong here. 
any help would be appreciated!

Thank you! Nick

```
Public Function GenerateNext(SourceFile As Variant, SourceSheet As String, SourceRange As String)

    Dim rsCon As Object
    Dim rsData As Object
    Dim szConnect As String
    Dim szSQL As String

    szSQL = "UPDATE [" & SourceSheet$ & "$] SET [First] = NULL ;"

     On Error GoTo SomethingWrong
    Application.StatusBar = "Retrieving data ....."


    szConnect = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" & _
                "Data Source=" & SourceFile & ";" & _
                "Extended Properties=Excel 8.0;"


    Set rsCon = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    Set rsData = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

    rsCon.Open szConnect
    'Run the query as adCmdText
    rsData.Open szSQL, rsCon, 0, 1, 1

    Exit Function

SomethingWrong:
    MsgBox "Something Wrong"
    On Error GoTo 0

End Function
```

Comment: Why do you have dollar signs stuck to your variables? I would think that  `SourceSheet` is a different variable than `SourceSheet$` which is unset and probably returning nothing. Either set "Option Explicit" for your code and/or `debug.print szSQL` so you can see what your SQL string looks like before having it shot over to Jet.

Comment: I believe that's how the query works here. I've used the similar patterns in some of my 'select' queries, and it works fine. Problem seems to something else, which I'm not able to figure out yet. - Nick

Comment: As a test you could try a SELECT query on the same sheet, cells, etc. I'm wondering if you can only write to an open workbook.

Comment: I had to correct the query. somehow " " are not being understood as equivalent to a blank value. I had to pass NULL to make that work. I've updated the code. Right now, the only problem I have is, I want to update first 40 rows, so how to pass the Range in the query?